# List all available indices via Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How to get a list of all available indices via the Java API?

With REST it's just the following HTTP-Request:

```
http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9200/_aliases
```

But for consistency it would be nice to do this via the Java API.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The equivalent using the Java API and the elasticsearch `org.elasticsearch.client.Client` class is:

```
 client.admin().cluster()
    .prepareState().execute()
    .actionGet().getState()
    .getMetaData().aliases();
```

Comment: Little Note: I mistakenly used `concreteAllIndices()` instead of your suggusted `aliases()` when I accepted your anwser. `aliases()` returns only a empty map if I use it, `concreteAllIndices()` instead returns a String-array with all indices. Although your anwser should be correct regarding of to be the _equivalent_ (not sure why the map is empty in my application).

Comment: that is because alias and indexes are two different concepts

Comment: Above answer doesn't work ES version as of 1.4.4 Instead use following. ObjectLookupContainer<String> mapAl = client.admin().cluster()
        .prepareState().execute()
        .actionGet().getState()
        .getMetaData().indices().keys();

Comment: client.admin().indices().stats(new IndicesStatsRequest()).actionGet().getIndices().keySet()

Works in version 1.4